# How do I get rid of an unwanted left margin on my Recent Posts widget inside my WordPress site's footer?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, margin, footer

I have Agent Ransack, a cool tool to mass search across many files. Now, I have four widgets in my WordPress site's footer but they are not aligned. I have discovered that there is 20px of left margin causing this, which is being applied to my Recent Posts widget (labelled News, but this is irrelevant). Regardless of what order the widgets are in, there is always a 20px left margin on this particular widget.

I've used my program to search for `margin-left: 20px`, `left: 20px`, etc. I've tried even with taking away the spaces in the those quotes. They returned results and I searched through every one of them, but nothing relevant... I even tried searching `20px` and going through every margin-related style. Nothing relevant.

Have I just missed it, or is it possible that the random left margin is not in my theme files at all? The other widgets are text, search and a custom menu - but these widgets are irrelevant really because it is always the News one that has this left margin.

Hopefully someone can give me some advice - in this situation, what would you do?

Comment: Could you please let me know that web page? I don't have a magic mirror.

Comment: You can save the static page with css using browser function. If you want to get answer, try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `.widget_container_mini`. When css use `display:inline-block`, you can see each block like block, but it deal with inline element. So browser do auto-spacing between inline-elements as a text. (You can think about text-wrapping).

If you want remove that margin, you can use the style below:

```
.widget_container_mini {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```